# How to restore production data in alfresco ..?

Tags: alfresco

Alfresco was installed in linux server and the data location was mapped as
**dir.root=/cameoreports**. We needed to re-install the server so We took the back up of /cameoreports and done the re installation. Post re install we installed the alfresco again and mapped **dir.root=/cameoreports**, but were getting alfrescoruntimeexception getmodelsdiff error while starting. Could you please provide the correct way to restore the contents.

Comment: If you're trying to "match" a fresh Alfresco install, with a complete backup of an old content store, that will not work. Is this the case?

Answer (score 3):

You should have taken full backup.

Full backup consist of following artifacts.

- **Content store Backup**
- **Index backup**
- **Database backup**

I do not see anything related to Database and Indexes in your post. That is the reason you are facing challenges.

If you have db backup and content store backup you can regenerate indexes but if you do not have database then you are in trouble.